# Java - debugging and optimization

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, optimization

Consider the following code:

```
public class BigArrayTest {

    private static int[][] bigArray = new int[10000][10000];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long lastTime = startTime;

        for (int i = 0 ; i < bigArray.length ; i++ ) {
            for (int j = 0 ; j < bigArray[0].length ; j++ ) {
                bigArray[j][i] = i+j;

            }
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(now - lastTime);

            lastTime = now;
        }
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println(endTime - startTime); // <= Break Point position
    }
}
```

When I run it in eclipse in run mode or in debug mode, I get similar outputs (overall run time is around 11 sec. in both cases) but, when I add a break point in the end of the code, the run time is as twice as long (around 21 sec.)

The more interesting case is when I turn the break point on and off while loops are being executed - the time of each loop varies between 1/3 millisec. when break point is off/on respectively.

I'm curious if this is due to running an un-optimized code in debug mode (and if so - why does it matter if I place a break point or not?) or just an overhead of the debugger checking for breakpoints, and skipping the test when break point array is empty.

I'm using an x64 eclipse luna v.20131219-0014 and JDK 1.8.0 for that matters...

**EDIT:**

As @pveentjer suggested, I edded an outside nested loop that runs 20 times, and got similar results:
Run -            218097 millisec.
Debug -          214877 millisec.
Debug with BP -  411354 millisec.

I also tried to put the break point in another method (that's being called from my code) and it seems it has no effect on performent wheather I turn this BP on and off.

Comment: Extract a method to be measured in order to get a better optimization than [OSR](http://www.azulsystems.com/blog/cliff/2011-11-22-what-the-heck-is-osr-and-why-is-it-bad-or-good).

Comment: I have experienced similar behavior of eclipse debugging and I guess it is because of overhead of checking break point conditions.

Comment: @maaartinus - extracting a method doesn't seem to have any effect on performence...

Answer (score 0):

Your benchmark is fundamentally broken because you don't run long enough. Try to run for at least a few minutes by repeating. This way at least the JIT has done its magic.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is written mostly in JAVA. So when the debug point is hit there is a lot of stuff which eclipse does so that we can get the information we need to debug. This necessarily takes time. Also eclipse is smart enough to have a check if there are bereakpoints are not. SO when there are no breakpoints the application runs as if its in normal run mode. But when there are breakpoints, eclipse retrieves the values of various properties at that break point and displays it to us. Hence the extra time is justified.

Comment: I get it that there's overhead of breaking in a breakpoint, but what I claim is that the execution is slower in debug mode even when no break point is hit.
Do you suggest eclipse is compiling both an optimized and a non optimized version of each method, and switch between the two versions if a breakpoint is inserted?

Comment: AFAIK eclipse source code is available for download. Will have to look at it to understand how eclipse debugger works